# Reactjs: performance between setState<number[]>() with setState<number[]>([])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two code for same work:

1:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<number[]>()

state && state.length > 0 && state.map(item => { //do something })
```

2:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<number[]>([])

state.map(item => { //do something })
```

Witch is better performance?

Comment: The difference will be immeasurably tiny.